# pandasの行とインデックスの切替

Tags: python, pandas

pandasのDataFrameに関する質問です．
インデックスに指定した行を代入するような操作は可能なのでしょうか？

e.g.)

```
index   A   B
    1   1.0 2.0
    2   3.0 4.0 
⇒２行目を代入する操作
index   3.0 4.0
    1   1.0 2.0
```

Comment: やりたい事がいまひとつわかりません。
「インデックスに指定した行を代入」とは何に対しての代入でしょうか？
指定した行の値をcolumn名に設定したいって事ですか？

Comment: はい．その通りです．指定した行の値をcolumn名にしたいと考えています．コラム名がA，Bであったところを，2行目の3,4　に変更したいです．説明が分りにくくてすみません．

Answer (score 1):

指定した行の要素をColumn名にする方法は、こんな感じで記述できると思います。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]], columns=['A','B'])

df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1], inplace=True)
print(df)
# =>    3.0  4.0
#    0  1.0  2.0
#    1  3.0  4.0
```

更に、２列目(index=1)が不要な場合は更に

`df.drop(1, inplace=True)`

して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

確かに問題の意味があいまいですがこういうことですか?

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]],index=range(1,3),columns=["A","B"])
df

>      A    B
> 1  1.0  2.0
> 2  3.0  4.0

df.loc[1,:]=df.loc[2,:]
df

>      A    B
> 1  3.0  4.0
> 2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]],index=range(1,3),columns=["A","B"])
print(df)

print('---')

df2 = df.T.set_index(2).T
print(df2)

print(df2.shape)
```

上記を実行して、以下をえます。

```
     A    B
1  1.0  2.0
2  3.0  4.0
---
2  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0
(1, 2)
```